# Can I use always on VPN device tunnel on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: vpn, remote-access, windows-10, rras

I am testing out always on VPN user and device tunnels in my home lab to evaluate for live deployment in our companies' environemnt.

My user tunnel is working flawlessly, but my device tunnel does not auto connect and when I connect via "rasphone" it seems to disconnect after a period of time or after I sign out of the machine.

Is this because I am using Windows 10 Pro with the device tunnel still being limited to Enterprise? Is there any other way I can test the device tunnel without having Windows 10 Enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my question posted here and answer provided: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/432512/is-it-possible-to-use-always-on-vpn-device-tunnel.html

This is currently only supported on Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Currently supported and recommended solution is to use Enterprise edition to have Device Tunnel with fallback to User Tunnel.

As I know it is possible to configure Device Tunnel for Profesional edition but will not run automaticaly.
To run this tunnel it would be necessary to configure task scheduled.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2199357-device-tunnel-on-win10-pro

I need to test it by myself.

I hoped I could find detailed guide to deploy it but I could not.